# How to append federated identities at sign-up/sign-in attempt?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

following the [Azure AD B2C account linkage](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-at-signup#azure-ad-b2c-account-linkage) I was able to successfully achieve `Scenario 1` and `Scenario 2` .

However, when I attempt to federated sign-up/sign-in for the second time using an account attached to the same email used first, a new user is created in contrast to an identity append.

The sample [account-linkage-unified](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-unified) seems the way to go, but from my understanding, the **linkage** must happen intentionally from the user.

It is reinforced at the account linkage sample:

> The sample on account linkage [unified] shows you how the user can correct the problem by joining the two accounts, but that is **active** action by the user.

### Scenario and expected identities

User `foo` uses the same `foo@email.com` for Facebook, Microsoft, Google, and Twitter accounts;

He does attempt to federated sign-up/sign-in using each of these accounts;

Expected accounts: 1

Expected identities:

```json
{
  "displayName": "Foo Smith",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "foo@email.com"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "facebook.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "live.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "345678"
    },
    {
        "signInType": "federated",
        "issuer": "google.com",
        "issuerAssignedId": "345678"
    },
    {
        "signInType": "federated",
        "issuer": "twitter.com",
        "issuerAssignedId": "345678"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, the [Azure AD B2C Community](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) folks has released a sample policy addressing this scenario:

- [Azure AD B2C Auto Account Link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/auto-account-linking)